# How to show that one not monotonous f doesn't have fixpoints?

Tags: functions, fixed-point-theorems, monotone-functions, fixed-points

I have a question about fixed points
If I have one function $f$ (that is not monotonous!) I would like to demostrate that this function hasn't fixed points.
I need to find a funciton $f$ for which this is valid. My problem is that I can not find a valid example of $f$, but mainly I don't know how to prove that this function hasn't any fixed points.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Think of $f(x)=x^2+1$.

Comment: Just a side remark: 'monotonous' is not the word. It is 'monotonic'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions that are not monotonic, but have fixed points. For example, the function $f(x)=x^2$ is not monotonic, yet it has a fixed point at $x=0$.

A function that is not monotonic that has no fixed points would be $g(x) = x^2+1$.

You can prove that this function has no fixed points by definition. Namely, to get its fixed points you need to solve $$x^2+1=x$$ This is an ordinary quadratic equation, which has no solutions, and thus there are no fixed points.

---

To show that $g$ is not monotonic, we will show that $g(x+1)-g(x)$ can sometimes be positive and it can sometimes be negative.

We have
$$g(x+1)-g(x) = (x+1)^2+1 - (x^2+1) = x^2+2x+1-x^2-1=2x$$
Depending on the sign of $x$ this can be positive or negative.

Comment: Hi! Tanks fot the help. I forgot something: for all x in the sample (real valued) x <= f(x)

Comment: @claudioz You can verify that $x\leq x^2+1$.

Comment: sorry but I do not understand how it can be not monotonous. I see that for all x in the domain such as x < x+1, the result of the function g is g(x) < g(x+1)

Comment: @claudioz For example, $g(-1) > g(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Are we assuming real valued? Use $f(x)=x^2+2$, its trivially nonmonotonous, and to test for fixed points show $x^2+2=x$ has no real valued solutions.

Comment: Hi! Tanks fot the help. I forgot something: for all x in the sample (real valued) x <= f(x)

Comment: That is true already. If $x \leq f(x)$, then $f(x)-x \geq 0$, and if you are dealing with monotone functions and fixed points, you should be able to solve a quadratic inequality.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have one function  (that is not monotonous!) I would like to
>   demostrate that this function hasn't fixed points.

$$ f(x) = x + 3 + 2   \sin x  $$
Since
$$ f(x) \geq x+1, $$
we have
$$  f(x) \neq x $$

However,
$$  f'(x) = 1 + 2 \cos x$$
is sometimes positive and sometimes negative

............